Why is a unit of stock worth $S_T$ a valid numeraire? Is $S_T^2$ a valid numeraire?
When we switch numeraires from $M$ to $S$, we change the measure from $\mathbb{Q}^M$ to $\mathbb{Q}^S$. I derived a closed-form formula for the payoff $S_T(S_T - K)\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T > K\}}$ here. How do I quickly test if $f(S_T)$ qualifies as a numeraire? Intuitively, the discounted values $f(S_T)/M(T)$ must be martingales under $\mathbb{Q}^M$. Are my explanations on point?

How can I argue that a unit of stock (non-dividends) $S_T$ is indeed a valid numeraire?

The random variable
$$
\begin{align*}
Z_T = \frac{S_T/S_0}{M_T/M_0}=\exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}T + \sigma W^{\mathbb{Q}^M}_T\right)
\end{align*}
$$
which is a $\mathbb{Q}^M$ martingale, with $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^M}[Z] = 1$. So, I can construct $\mathbb{Q}^S(A) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^M}[Z1_A]$, it is a valid measure.

How can I argue that a dividend-paying stock fails to qualify as a numeraire?

The random variable
$$
\begin{align*}
Z_T = \frac{S_T^{div}/S_0^{div}}{M_T/M_0}=\exp\left(\left(-q -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma W^{\mathbb{Q}^M}_T\right)
\end{align*}
$$
which not a $\mathbb{Q}^M$ martingale, with $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^M}[Z] = e^{-qT}$. So, we can't construct $\mathbb{Q}^{S^{div}}$.

Are powers of the stock price $S_T^{\alpha}$, $\alpha > 1$ valid numeraires?


So if the stock price can go to zero (or below) it is NOT a valid numeraire. Although under the common GBM assumption it does not go to zero so it is valid. But in real life ...

Needs to positive and self-financing - so if the stock pays dividends it is not a valid numeraire for example. The stock and its dividends reinvested is though.

You say it correctly: if $N_t$ is the old numeraire, any asset $M$ such that $\frac{M_t}{N_t}$ is an N-martingale is a valid numeraire (as long as it is positive).
This means that a numeraire must be a tradable-asset and $S_t^2$ is not (it has convexity and you can price an option on it, but $S_t^2$ is never the price process of a tradable asset).
You can see why the restriction: take a simple model with a bank account $B_t$  (deterministic rates = 0) and a non dividend paying stock.
When you change measure, the drift of $S_t$ changes, an only that. Both assets ($B_t$ and $S_t$) must stay martingales when discounted by any numeraire.

If $S_t$ is a numeraire, this means that $\frac{B_t}{S_t}$ and $\frac{S_t}{S_t}=1$ must be martingales. And it is possible since this is really only 1 constraint (the one for $B_t$).

If you allowed $S_t^2$ to be a numeraire, then you could not make both $\frac{B_t}{S_t^2}$ and $\frac{S_t}{S^2_t}=\frac{1}{S_t}$ martingales at the same time by changing only one drift.

If the stock pays divided, the reinvested stock is a valid numeraire.



Too long for a comment:
Just to add to Andrea's answer, if $X_T$ is any state variable (not necessarily tradable), and $F(X_T) > 0$, then you can use $E_t [ F(X_T) ]$ as a numéraire and clearly $F(X_T) = E_T^\mathbb Q [ F(X_T) ]$. In your example $S_T^2 = E_T^\mathbb Q [ S_T^2]$.
One of my favourite and not so well-known application of this is that in a stochastic volatility model setting with $\rho = 0$ between the spot price and the instantaneous volatility, $dS_t = \sigma_t S_t dW_t$, the volswap price is given by
$$
E_t^\mathbb Q [\sigma_{t,T} ] = E_t^\mathbb H [ (\log S_T)_+ ] = E_t^\mathbb Q \left[ \frac{ \sqrt{S_T} }{E_t[ \sqrt{S_T} ]}  (\log S_T)_+ \right]
$$
where $\sigma^2_{t,T} := \frac{1}{T-}\int_t^T \sigma^2_u du$
and the "half-measure" $\mathbb H$ is the measure under which $S_t/E_t [ \sqrt{S_T} ]$ is a martingale.
To see this you can first assume $\sigma$ is deterministic to get a feel for the calculations, and then in the stoch vol case for $\rho = 0$ apply conditioning.
(I've taken $r=0$ but principle remains the same for $r\neq 0$.)

Do I understand correctly that, for $F(X_T) > 0$, the price process $V_t = E_t[F(X_T)]$ of a derivative contract that pays $F(X_T)$ is strictly positive (monotonicity of expectations) and hence can be used as numeraire? For example, in Joshi's paper, he uses the power numeraire $\mathbb{E}^{Q}_t[S_T^{\alpha}]$, $\alpha > 0$.

@Quasar Yes if the payout is strictly positive a.s. then the price is as well. And since the expectation of the (discounted) claim is a martingale under the Q measure you can use it as numeraire.
